# Ruby Classes; Error: Uninitialized constant BookInStock::ArguementError (NameError)

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby but trying my best to grasp it. The ques is...

Define a class BookInStock which represents a book with an isbn number, isbn, and price of the book as a floating-point number, price, as attributes. The constructor should accept the ISBN number (a string) as the first argument and price as second argument, and should raise ArgumentError (one of Ruby's built-in exception types) if the ISBN number is the empty string or if the price is less than or equal to zero.

Include the proper getters and setters for these attributes. Include a method price_as_string that returns the price of the book with a leading dollar sign and trailing zeros, that is, a price of 20 should display as "$20.00" and a price of 33.8 should display as "$33.80".

My code:-

```
class BookInStock
  #getters and setters
  attr_reader :isbn, :price

  def isbn= (isbn)
    if isbn == ''
      raise ArguementError.new("Must have an ISBN number")
    end
    @isbn = isbn
  end

  def price= (price)
    price = price.to_f
    if price <= 0
      raise ArguementError.new("Must have price")
    end
    @price = price
  end

  def initialize(isbn, price)
    self.isbn = @isbn
    self.price = @price
  end

  def self.price_as_string
    return "$" + sprinff("%.2f", @price)
  end
end
```

However, I'm getting an error when I try

```
BookInStock.new('',9.00)
```

I get a `Uninitialized constant BookInStock::ArgumentError (NameError)`

Upon doing some research on the error it says that I may be referring to a class or module that doesn't exist?
PLease help, thanks

Comment: def initialize(isbn, price)
    self.isbn = isbn
    self.price = price  I actually this not what was printed above

Answer (score 1):

You have made a small typo.

Its `ArgumentError` not `ArguementError`

Please refer

> http://apidock.com/ruby/ArgumentError

Alright. You have few more problems too. Lets take them one by one.

Your Constructor:
Inside your constructor you have the code,

```
self.isbn = @isbn
self.price = @price
```

When you write a variable with the `@` character, it referes to the `instance variable`. So when you are writing `self.isbn = @isbn`, you are actually doing `@isbn=@isbn` and you are not assigning the argument passed to the constructor to `@isbn`. So you should do:

```
self.isbn = isbn
self.price = price
```

Next is your `price_as_string` method. When you declare a method as `self.method_name` it becomes a class method. Such methods are called using the Class like so - `BookInStock.price_as_string`. But the attribute used inside this method(`@price`) is not a class variable but an instance variable. And hence your `price_as_string` should be either a instance method (written without `self.`) or this `self.price_as_string` must take price as an argument. like so - `self.price_as_string(price)`. But a good Object Oriented design would be to have this as an instance method.

Thanks `@arup`

Comment: Yes..you are rigt..But there are some more mistakes OP did... tell also those.